# Suggest [password-recovery] as synonym of [account-recovery]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Isn't [password-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) a subset of [account-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-recovery)? I mean, if you're trying to recover your password you're obviously trying to recover access to your account, no? (The reverse is not necessarily true, of course.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request is complete. [password-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) is now a synonym of [account-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-recovery)